# Compare correlation coefficients or use a mixed effect model?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, mixed-model

I have a dataset of documents from 13 government organisations published between 2000 and 2020. The dataset contains between 18 and 20 million words. I have a measure that tells me how unique a word used in the dataset is to an organisation -- specificity -- and a measure that tells me how fad-like a word used in the dataset is (whether the word is more likely to appear in one point of time in particular compared to other points in time) -- volatility (https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09665). For each organisation I wanted to see if there was a relationship between the specificities and volatilities of the words used in the organisation's documents using Spearman's rank correlation coefficient. I found a significant positive correlation between specificity and volatility for all organisations. I also found one organisation consistently has a lower rho than the other organisations across all years, and I think this is potentially a useful result.

I was wondering what's the most appropriate way to assess this difference between organisations' correlations between specificity and volatility? I thought about using the Fisher z transformation to test if the difference between correlations is significant, but I came across these two pages: [Testing Spearman's rho between-groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59714/testing-spearmans-rho-between-groups), https://garstats.wordpress.com/2019/06/17/compindcorr/

Both say that it's better to bring all the groups into a single model (not entirely sure what this means) rather than test for differences between correlations, with the wordpress page saying one should use a mixed effect model. Is this what I should do? I don't think there's any reason to assume a linear relationship between specificity and volatility (example scatter plot below), so should I use a non-linear mixed effect model? Or is there something that's completely different I should be doing to assess differences between organisations' specificity-volatility relationships?

I don't come from a stats/maths background, so I'm a bit lost!

[image: Example scatter plot]